# Avoiding UAC but launching an elevated process using a windows service

Tags: winapi, uac, elevated-privileges

I have a non-interactive service running as a the privileged SYSTEM user on Windows machines, and I need it to launch a given executable as an elevated process.

I have managed to launch a child process as SYSTEM, using WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), finding a system process and duplicating it's token. Similarly, I can launch a non-elevated process as a regular user. But I need to launch the process as the regular user, but with elevated privileges - so that I don't have to show UAC, but the process is running as the appropriate user.

I am not trying to bypass UAC - since the user already agreed to installing the service. I am trying to mitigate an inconvenience. I have found a [similar, unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324382/launch-elevated-user-process-from-session-0-service) - but asked again in hope of maybe getting an answer.

Comment: Assuming that you're using WTSQueryUserToken to get a token for the interactive user, and that the interactive user is an administrator, you should be able to get the elevated token using GetTokenInformation with the TokenLinkedToken option.

Comment: On a side note, it should be possible (and more efficient) to launch a child process as SYSTEM by duplicating your own SYSTEM token and then changing the session ID using SetTokenInformation and the TokenSessionId option.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for the ideas! The linked token idea works ok. If you convert it to an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Liosan: I have similar problem. i have to launch the process in all the active session. For that i am using WTSEnumerateSessions() to got all active session and launching the process. But i want to run the process in that session in admin mode(run as admin). Can you tell me how to do it. To Get the session token i used WTSQueryUserToken() API and to launch the process i used CreateProcessAsUser() API. Also my service is local service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a filtered token for the interactive user - for example, one retrieved via [WTSQueryUserToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - you can retrieve the unfiltered ("elevated") token by using the [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the TokenLinkedToken option.