# Launching A process as admin from windows service

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, service

I am working on a sample, in that i have a windows service which launches a process(UserApplication.exe). To launch a process form windows service i got sample form this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite.

This works fine. But the problem is, launched process(UserApplication.exe) is calling an API FilterAttach(). When the process(UserApplication.exe) calls this API then it failed with - access denied.

But if i run the same process(UserApplication.exe) by right click and run as admin then it works fine no error and every thing works fine.

please let me know how to run a process as admin form a service.

Also i tried to set the manifest file of that exe to run as admin but no help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like you've wound up with a filtered token, though it's hard to say for sure without seeing the exact code you're using.  Assuming that is indeed the problem, [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23793926/886887).

Comment: @ Harry Johnston : the code i used for service  from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite. And FilterAttach() API i am calling from a win32 application(UserApplication.exe).

Comment: You haven't modified the code at all?  Are you running Windows Vista?  I don't think that code will work in Windows 7, because it is looking for a process that doesn't exist (at least not on my machine).

Comment: I did not modified it. But in my machine i can see that process. Also i used WTSQueryUserToken() API to get the session ID and passed it to CreateProcessAsUser() API. Still it is not working.

Comment: As per the answer I linked to, the user token retrieved by WTSQueryUserToken is a filtered token.  That is, it doesn't have admin privilege.  To convert the filtered token into a token with admin privilege, use GetTokenInformation with the TokenLinkedToken option.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: can you provide an example. I dont find any example in msdn