# How to run a program from windows service with administrator privileges

Tags: windows-services

I created a windows service that runs a program on windows startup, but with this solution the program runs without administrator privileges. However, if I run the program by click on the program's shortcut on the Start menu, it runs with administrator privileges

I used this code to run the program:

```
ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;

ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(program_name, out procInfo);
```

So how to run this program with administrator privileges?
Thanks

Comment: with, or without? I think you want to ask how to start the program from windows service, without having elevated privileges.

Comment: I need to run with administrator privileges

Comment: Go to START > Run, and type `services.msc` and run it. Then find the service, and right click to view properties. Go to logon tab and please tell us what user is set on logon tab.

Comment: it's Local System account

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding UAC but launching an elevated process using a windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756176/avoiding-uac-but-launching-an-elevated-process-using-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

**To run as administrator (program)**

Right click and choose "Run as administrator" (one-time / ad hoc)

or right click and choose properties > Compatibility > check "Run this program as administrator" (set it permanently; can also be handy for setting this property on a shortcut (which is basically what Start menu items are))

**To not run as administrator (service)**

For services, to make it not run as an admin, open the services snap in (run `services.msc` from command prompt) and right click to edit properties of the service, then update the user info on the "Logon" tab.

**UPDATE**

It looks like you've used some code from a CodeProject article that wraps the Windows API function `CreateProcessAsUser` (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite). Make sure you read that article and follow the steps. You may not have set the correct user on the service, or your current user may not have correct perms, or may not be a member of Administrators, etc.

Comment: But when I launch this program from the Windows service, it doesn't run as administrator

Comment: That is the opposite of what you said in your question. Review and update your question please. Also, same thing applies .. just view properties of the service, change the Logon tab to be admin user.

Comment: IIRC, that code only works on Windows Vista and not on later versions of Windows.