# C++ Use CreateProcessAsUser to Launch Program from Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, service

I have a windows service that can call programs using CreateProcess.  The only problem is that they run in session zero.  I want them to run as administrator.  I know that I need to use the CreateProcessAsUser function, but I am not sure how to get the right token.

I could use ImpersonateLoggedOnUser, but I don't want the user to enter a username and password every time I want to create an admin process.

Comment: If your service is running as local system (or in any other account that has administrator privilege) then you can just use CreateProcess and the new processes will have the same privilege as the service.  Do you mean that you want the processes to run in the currently logged on user's session, so that they can interact with the user?

Comment: And if so, should they be running in the user's account, or the same account as the system service?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear enough.  I want to interact with the user in the user's account, but I want to be an administrator.

Comment: Huh?  Do you mean you want the process to interact with the user in the user's *session* but to run in an administrative security context?

Comment: Yes, just as if the user right-clicked the program and selected "Run As Administrator".

Comment: Running in the user's security context, then, but with elevation.  OK, pretty sure that's a duplicate.  I'll see if I can find it.  Edit - here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23756176/886887